# WCF TCP Transport Security and WIF

Tags: wcf, wif, nettcpbinding

My company uses WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) to secure our sevices.  Currently we only use WIF over HTTPS.  However, we need to secure a TCP endpoint and I'm running into some trouble.

I'm getting following exception:

```
The '{binding name}'.'http://tempuri.org/' binding for the '{IService}'.
'http://tempuri.org/' contract is configured with an authentication mode that requires 
transport level integrity and confidentiality. However the transport cannot provide 
integrity and confidentiality.
```

In order to get WIF into the picture we have to do this inside the service host:

```
var istp = new IssuedSecurityTokenParameters(_TokenType, _IssuerAddress, _IssuerBinding) // issuer address/binding do not matter for this, but must provide something
{
    RequireDerivedKeys = false, 
    KeyType = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKeyType.BearerKey
}; 

TransportSecurity = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
TransportSecurity.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(istp);
TransportSecurity.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12;
```

I can't take those lines of code out but I don't know what configuration I'm missing to make this work with TCP.  Any help at all would be great.